# How to get a range of XML elements that contains certain "price" in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I'm trying to get a range of values of a XML file that are in certain price range with linq, I'm not pretty sure how to do it, but I know how to get the price of each Element.

I've tried to get into a list the prices for each element and then apply all that is in range, but I don't know how to keep the brand due I have to display the brand of existing cars in price range.

XML:

```
 <Garage>
   <Car id="001">
    <Brand>Foo</Brand>
    <Price>100</Price>
   </Car>
   <Car id="002">
     <Brand>Bar</Brand>
     <Price>130</Price>
   </Car>
   <Car id="003">
     <Brand>Re</Brand>
     <Price>110</Price>
   </Car>
 </Garage>
```

Code:

```
 var xmlStr = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Path\To\Xml");
 var str = XElement.Parse(xmlStr);
 var carInRange = str.Elements("Car").Where(x => x.Element("Price").Value.Equals("100")).ToList();
```

Obviously I'm just getting just "100" values, but I'm expecting to get for example ranges between 100 and 120 (just as an example) but not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to parse the price to a `decimal` or an other numeric type. Then you can perform a range check. For example

```
var carInRange = str.Elements("Car")
                     .Where(x => decimal.TryParse(x.Element("Price").Value, out decimal price)
                                 && price < 100m))
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: Is doing almost what I exactly need but I want to specify minimum price and maximum price, in this case fo example
double minimumPrice=100;
double maximumPrice=120;

Comment: You can use any conditional expression you want. In your case you may use `decimal.TryParse(...) && price >= minimumPrice && price <= maximumPrice`.

Answer (score 2):

What about using XPath ? It's a bit more readable than nested linq manipulation:

```
var carsInRange = xml.XPathSelectElements("/Car[Price > 100 and Price <= 120]");
```

If you want to stick on Linq query, you can try

```
var cars = xml.Elements("Car");
var carsInRange2 = from c in cars
                   let price = (decimal)c.Element("Price")
                   where price > 100 && price <= 120
                   select c;

Console.WriteLine(carsInRange2.Count());
```

Complete sample:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = @"<Garage>
                       <Car id=""001"">
                        <Brand>Foo</Brand>
                        <Price>100</Price>
                       </Car>
                       <Car id=""002"">
                         <Brand>Bar</Brand>
                         <Price>130</Price>
                       </Car>
                       <Car id=""003"">
                         <Brand>Re</Brand>
                         <Price>110</Price>
                       </Car>
                     </Garage>";

        var xml = XElement.Parse(data);

        var carsInRange = xml.XPathSelectElements("/Car[Price > 100 and Price <= 120]");

        Console.WriteLine(carsInRange.Count());

        var cars = xml.Elements("Car");
        var carsInRange2 = from c in cars
                           let price = (decimal)c.Element("Price")
                           where price > 100 && price <= 120
                           select c;

        Console.WriteLine(carsInRange2.Count());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```